# Line breaks between function definitions

Tags: clang-format

Is there any way to to automatically insert spaces between function definitions. E.g. my initial sources are:

```
void
func1()
{
    // func1 body.
}
void
func2()
{
    // func2 body.
}
```

I would like it to be reformatted to:

```
void
func1()
{
    // func1 body.
}


void
func2()
{
    // func2 body.
}
```

And if there are more line breaks, fixed number of them should be kept.

Comment: They really need to add this and the ability to insert blank lines in other obvious spots too (e.g. - after variable definitions).

Comment: Possible in clang-format 14 - see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70732683/how-to-add-blank-lines-between-definitions/70732858

Answer (score 43):

As far as I can tell, there's currently no way to force clang-format to insert blank lines between consecutive functions where there currently are none.  IMHO this is a huge missing feature.

Comment: Is that still not possible in 2020?

Comment: Is that still not possible in 2022?

Comment: @SaeedMasoomi It is possible in clang-format ≥ 14. Look at the option _SeparateDefinitionBlocks_.

See the documentation [here](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#configurable-format-style-options).

Comment: Current clang-format can insert a single line, but not more. :-/

Answer (score 24):

Your best bet is to set 'MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 2' inside .clang-format file to let clang-format keep 2 lines intact.

Answer (score 23):

As mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70732858/3034368) with clang-format 14, you can use the following in your config file:

```yaml
SeparateDefinitionBlocks: Always
```

The other possible values are `Leave`, to leave the spacing of definition blocks as-is, or `Never`, to remove empty lines between definition blocks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SeparateDefinitionBlocks: Always
EmptyLineBeforeAccessModifier: LogicalBlock
```

above two options will solve your question

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).