# How to add blank lines between definitions?

Tags: c++, clang-format

I successfully managed to make clang-format format my code like iIwant. However, there is one thing that bugs me:

I want a blank line between definitions of structs/classes/functions and between declarations of functions. Currently, when formatting, clang-format removes blank lines, which makes everything condensed.

Here is my file:

```
---
AlignAfterOpenBracket: DontAlign
AlignTrailingComments: "true"
AllowAllArgumentsOnNextLine: "false"
AllowAllConstructorInitializersOnNextLine: "true"
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: "false"
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: "false"
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: "false"
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: None
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: Never
AllowShortLambdasOnASingleLine: None
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: "false"
AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: "false"
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: "Yes"
BinPackArguments: "true"
BinPackParameters: "true"
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: "false"
BreakConstructorInitializers: AfterColon
BreakInheritanceList: AfterColon
ColumnLimit: "170"
CompactNamespaces: "false"
ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine: "true"
IncludeBlocks: Merge
IndentCaseLabels: "true"
IndentPPDirectives: BeforeHash
IndentWidth: "4"
IndentWrappedFunctionNames: "false"
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: "false"
Language: Cpp
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: "0"
NamespaceIndentation: All
PointerAlignment: Left
SortIncludes: "true"
SortUsingDeclarations: "true"
SpaceAfterCStyleCast: "false"
SpaceAfterLogicalNot: "false"
SpaceAfterTemplateKeyword: "false"
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: "true"
SpaceBeforeCpp11BracedList: "false"
SpaceBeforeCtorInitializerColon: "false"
SpaceBeforeInheritanceColon: "false"
SpaceBeforeParens: Never
SpaceBeforeRangeBasedForLoopColon: "false"
SpaceInEmptyParentheses: "false"
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: "3"
SpacesInAngles: "false"
SpacesInCStyleCastParentheses: "false"
SpacesInContainerLiterals: "false"
SpacesInParentheses: "false"
SpacesInSquareBrackets: "false"
Standard: Auto
UseTab: Always
TabWidth: "4"
```

Here is how it looks:

[image]

I want a blank line between the two structs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have

```
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: "0"
```

which needs to be set to `1` instead, to ensure that multiple empty lines between definitions are not removed.

Importantly, the value needs to be an unsigned type, not a string.

So the correct setting for what you want should be

```
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 1
```

---

Note that this won't work if you don't already have at least one blank line between definitions, but from clang-format 14, you can use

```
SeparateDefinitionBlocks : Always
```

which will add an empty line between every definition. The other options are `Leave` which doesn't change anything, and `Never`, which will remove blank lines, if any.

I don't think there's an option that lets you do this in previous versions.

Source: [Clang format style options](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html).

Comment: Thank you. MaxEmptyLinesToKeep only works if there are already empty lines. SeparateDefinitionBlocks helps!

Comment: @Raildex Yeah, if you have clang-format 14, that's definitely the superior option.