Clang - Allman not adding a line break
I have this C code and I'm using Clang in Visual Studio Code to auto-format when I save the file. I would like to add line breaks after my statements as seen below. I have included both C examples of what I am trying to achieve plus my Clang formatting.
Been trying to figure this out for about 4 hours now. It refuses to add a new line between my functions.
int function(UINT32 debounce_time, UINT8 debounce_count)
{
    int i;
    
    button.debounce_interval = debounce_time;
    
    if(1)
    {
        dosomething();
    }
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_PIN_HISTORY; i += 2)
    {
        button.pin_history[i] = 0;
    }
    for (i = 1; i < MAX_PIN_HISTORY; i += 2)
    {
        button.pin_history[i] = 1;
    }
    return;
}

However, I want it to be formatted like this (line breaks in-between the statements)
int function(UINT32 debounce_time, UINT8 debounce_count)
{
    int i;

    button.debounce_interval = debounce_time;

    if(1)
    {
        dosomething();
    }
    
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_PIN_HISTORY; i += 2)
    {
        button.pin_history[i] = 0;
    }
    
    for (i = 1; i < MAX_PIN_HISTORY; i += 2)
    {
        button.pin_history[i] = 1;
    }
    
    return;
}

How can I do that? Here is my Clang file.
# Format Style Options - Created with Clang Power Tools
---
AlignAfterOpenBracket: DontAlign
AlignOperands: DontAlign
AlignTrailingComments: false
AllowAllArgumentsOnNextLine: false
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: false
BasedOnStyle: Google
BreakBeforeBraces: Allman
BreakBeforeInheritanceComma: false
BreakBeforeConceptDeclarations: true
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: true
BreakStringLiterals: false
ColumnLimit: 150
ContinuationIndentWidth: 2
IncludeBlocks: Preserve
IndentGotoLabels: false
IndentPPDirectives: BeforeHash
IndentWidth: 8
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: true
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 2
PointerAlignment: Right
ReflowComments: false
SortIncludes: false
SpaceInEmptyBlock: true
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 1
UseTab: ForIndentation
...

Thanks.

I found this topic but it doesn't work for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27121457/line-breaks-between-function-definitions

if(1) with no space is inconsistent with for (i = 1; ...

"line breaks in-between the statements" your example shows line breaks between blocks, not statements.
